# Parse multiple xml with the same input file with python

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xpath

I have the input file as below going upto 100k Records in a SINGLE file

```
<pain001><CstmrCdtTrfInitn><GrpHdr><MsgId>ABC/120928/CCT001</MsgId><CreDtTm>2012-09-28T14:07:00</CreDtTm><NbOfTxs>100000</NbOfTxs><CtrlSum>11500000</CtrlSum> <InitgPty><Nm>ABC Corporation</Nm><PstlAdr><StrtNm>Times Square</StrtNm><BldgNb>7</BldgNb><PstCd>NY 10036</PstCd><TwnNm>New York</TwnNm><Ctry>US</Ctry></PstlAdr></InitgPty></GrpHdr><PmtInf><PmtInfId>CARCORP/086</PmtInfId><PmtMtd>TRF</PmtMtd><BtchBookg>false</BtchBookg><ReqdExctnDt>2012-09-29</ReqdExctnDt><Dbtr><Nm>CARCORP INC</Nm><PstlAdr><StrtNm>Times Square</StrtNm><BldgNb>7</BldgNb><PstCd>NY 10036</PstCd><TwnNm>New York</TwnNm><Ctry>US</Ctry></PstlAdr></Dbtr><DbtrAcct><Id><Othr><Id>00125574999</Id></Othr></Id></DbtrAcct><DbtrAgt><FinInstnId><BICFI>BBBBUS33</BICFI></FinInstnId></DbtrAgt><CdtTrfTxInf><PmtId><InstrId>ABC/120928/CCT001/01</InstrId><EndToEndId>ABC/4562/4</EndToEndId></PmtId><Amt><InstdAmt Ccy="JPY">100</InstdAmt></Amt><ChrgBr>SHAR</ChrgBr><CdtrAgt><FinInstnId><BICFI>AAAAGB2L</BICFI></FinInstnId></CdtrAgt><Cdtr><Nm>DEF Electronics</Nm><PstlAdr><AdrLine>Corn Exchange 5th Floor</AdrLine><AdrLine>Mark Lane 55</AdrLine><AdrLine>EC3R7NE London</AdrLine><AdrLine>GB</AdrLine></PstlAdr></Cdtr><CdtrAcct><Id><Othr><Id>23683707994125</Id></Othr></Id></CdtrAcct><Purp><Cd>GDDS</Cd></Purp><RmtInf><Strd><RfrdDocInf><Tp><CdOrPrtry><Cd>CINV</Cd></CdOrPrtry></Tp><Nb>4562</Nb><RltdDt>2012-09-08</RltdDt></RfrdDocInf></Strd></RmtInf></CdtTrfTxInf></PmtInf></CstmrCdtTrfInitn></pain001>
<pain001><CstmrCdtTrfInitn><GrpHdr><MsgId>ABC/120928/CCT001</MsgId><CreDtTm>2012-09-28T14:07:00</CreDtTm><NbOfTxs>100000</NbOfTxs><CtrlSum>11500000</CtrlSum> <InitgPty><Nm>ABC Corporation</Nm><PstlAdr><StrtNm>Times Square</StrtNm><BldgNb>7</BldgNb><PstCd>NY 10036</PstCd><TwnNm>New York</TwnNm><Ctry>US</Ctry></PstlAdr></InitgPty></GrpHdr><PmtInf><PmtInfId>CARCORP/086</PmtInfId><PmtMtd>TRF</PmtMtd><BtchBookg>false</BtchBookg><ReqdExctnDt>2012-09-29</ReqdExctnDt><Dbtr><Nm>CARCORP INC</Nm><PstlAdr><StrtNm>Times Square</StrtNm><BldgNb>7</BldgNb><PstCd>NY 10036</PstCd><TwnNm>New York</TwnNm><Ctry>US</Ctry></PstlAdr></Dbtr><DbtrAcct><Id><Othr><Id>00125574999</Id></Othr></Id></DbtrAcct><DbtrAgt><FinInstnId><BICFI>BBBBUS33</BICFI></FinInstnId></DbtrAgt><CdtTrfTxInf><PmtId><InstrId>ABC/120928/CCT001/01</InstrId><EndToEndId>ABC/4562/4</EndToEndId></PmtId><Amt><InstdAmt Ccy="JPY">100</InstdAmt></Amt><ChrgBr>SHAR</ChrgBr><CdtrAgt><FinInstnId><BICFI>AAAAGB2L</BICFI></FinInstnId></CdtrAgt><Cdtr><Nm>DEF Electronics</Nm><PstlAdr><AdrLine>Corn Exchange 5th Floor</AdrLine><AdrLine>Mark Lane 55</AdrLine><AdrLine>EC3R7NE London</AdrLine><AdrLine>GB</AdrLine></PstlAdr></Cdtr><CdtrAcct><Id><Othr><Id>23683707994125</Id></Othr></Id></CdtrAcct><Purp><Cd>GDDS</Cd></Purp><RmtInf><Strd><RfrdDocInf><Tp><CdOrPrtry><Cd>CINV</Cd></CdOrPrtry></Tp><Nb>4562</Nb><RltdDt>2012-09-08</RltdDt></RfrdDocInf></Strd></RmtInf></CdtTrfTxInf></PmtInf></CstmrCdtTrfInitn></pain001>
```

I have used list comprehension with Xpath as my logic to parse the value

```
def parsexml():
 net=[]
 tree = ET.parse('pain1.xml')
 root = tree.getroot()



 grp1x = [e.text for e in root.findall('CstmrCdtTrfInitn/GrpHdr/MsgId')]
 grp1y = [e.text for e in root.findall('CstmrCdtTrfInitn/GrpHdr/CreDtTm')]
 grp1 = [e.text for e in root.findall('CstmrCdtTrfInitn/GrpHdr/InitgPty/Nm')]
 grp2 = [e.text for e in root.findall('CstmrCdtTrfInitn/GrpHdr/CreDtTm')]
 grp3 = [e.text for e in root.findall('CstmrCdtTrfInitn/GrpHdr/NbOfTxs')]
 grp4 = [e.text for e in root.findall('CstmrCdtTrfInitn/GrpHdr/CtrlSum')]
 grp5 = [e.text for e in root.findall('CstmrCdtTrfInitn/GrpHdr/InitgPty/PstlAdr/StrtNm')]
 grp6 = [e.text for e in root.findall('CstmrCdtTrfInitn/GrpHdr/InitgPty/PstlAdr/BldgNb')]
 grp7 = [e.text for e in root.findall('CstmrCdtTrfInitn/GrpHdr/InitgPty/PstlAdr/PstCd')]
 grp8 = [e.text for e in root.findall('CstmrCdtTrfInitn/GrpHdr/InitgPty/PstlAdr/TwnNm')]
 grp9 = [e.text for e in root.findall('CstmrCdtTrfInitn/GrpHdr/InitgPty/PstlAdr/Ctry')]
 grp10 = [e.text for e in root.findall('CstmrCdtTrfInitn/PmtInf/PmtInfId')]
 grp11 = [e.text for e in root.findall('CstmrCdtTrfInitn/PmtInf/PmtMtd')]
 grp12 = [e.text for e in root.findall('CstmrCdtTrfInitn/PmtInf/BtchBookg')]
 grp13 = [e.text for e in root.findall('CstmrCdtTrfInitn/PmtInf/ReqdExctnDt')]
 grp14 = [e.text for e in root.findall('CstmrCdtTrfInitn/PmtInf/Dbtr/Nm')]
 grp15 = [e.text for e in root.findall('CstmrCdtTrfInitn/PmtInf/Dbtr/PstlAdr/StrtNm')]
 grp16 = [e.text for e in root.findall('CstmrCdtTrfInitn/PmtInf/Dbtr/PstlAdr/BldgNb')]
 grp17 = [e.text for e in root.findall('CstmrCdtTrfInitn/PmtInf/Dbtr/PstlAdr/PstCd')]
 grp18 = [e.text for e in root.findall('CstmrCdtTrfInitn/PmtInf/Dbtr/PstlAdr/TwnNm')]
 grp19 = [e.text for e in root.findall('CstmrCdtTrfInitn/PmtInf/Dbtr/PstlAdr/Ctry')]
 grp20 = [e.text for e in root.findall('CstmrCdtTrfInitn/PmtInf/DbtrAcct/Id/Othr/Id')]
 grp21 = [e.text for e in root.findall('CstmrCdtTrfInitn/PmtInf/DbtrAgt/FinInstnId/BICFI')]
 grp22 = [e.text for e in root.findall('CstmrCdtTrfInitn/PmtInf/CdtTrfTxInf/PmtId/InstrId')]
 grp23 = [e.text for e in root.findall('CstmrCdtTrfInitn/PmtInf/CdtTrfTxInf/PmtId/EndToEndId')]
 grp24 = [e.text for e in root.findall('CstmrCdtTrfInitn/PmtInf/CdtTrfTxInf/Amt/InstdAmt')]
 grp25= [e.text for e in root.findall('CstmrCdtTrfInitn/PmtInf/CdtTrfTxInf/Amt/InstdAmt[@Ccy="JPY"]')]
 grp26 = [e.text for e in root.findall('CstmrCdtTrfInitn/PmtInf/CdtTrfTxInf/ChrgBr')]
 grp27 = [e.text for e in root.findall('CstmrCdtTrfInitn/PmtInf/CdtTrfTxInf/CdtrAgt/FinInstnId/BICFI')]
 grp28 = [e.text for e in root.findall('CstmrCdtTrfInitn/PmtInf/CdtTrfTxInf/Cdtr/Nm')]
 grp29 = [e.text for e in root.findall('CstmrCdtTrfInitn/PmtInf/CdtTrfTxInf/Cdtr/PstlAdr/AdrLine[1]')]
 grp30 = [e.text for e in root.findall('CstmrCdtTrfInitn/PmtInf/CdtTrfTxInf/Cdtr/PstlAdr/AdrLine[2]')]
 grp31 = [e.text for e in root.findall('CstmrCdtTrfInitn/PmtInf/CdtTrfTxInf/Cdtr/PstlAdr/AdrLine[3]')]
 grp32 = [e.text for e in root.findall('CstmrCdtTrfInitn/PmtInf/CdtTrfTxInf/Cdtr/PstlAdr/AdrLine[4]')]
 grp33 = [e.text for e in root.findall('pain001/CstmrCdtTrfInitn/PmtInf/CdtTrfTxInf/CdtrAcct/Id/Othr/Id')]
 grp34 = [e.text for e in root.findall('pain001/CstmrCdtTrfInitn/PmtInf/CdtTrfTxInf/Purp/Cd')]
 grp35 = [e.text for e in root.findall('CstmrCdtTrfInitn/PmtInf/CdtTrfTxInf/RmtInf/Strd/RfrdDocInf/Tp/CdOrPrtry/Cd')]
 grp36 = [e.text for e in root.findall('CstmrCdtTrfInitn/PmtInf/CdtTrfTxInf/RmtInf/Strd/RfrdDocInf/Nb')]
 grp37= [e.text for e in root.findall('CstmrCdtTrfInitn/PmtInf/CdtTrfTxInf/RmtInf/Strd/RfrdDocInf/RltdDt')]


  net = ",".join(grp1x+grp1y+grp1 + grp2 + grp3 + grp4 +grp5+grp6+grp7+grp8+grp9+grp10+grp11+grp12+grp13+grp14+grp15+grp16+grp17+grp18+grp19+grp20+grp21+grp22+grp23+grp24+grp25+grp26+grp27+grp28+grp29+grp30+grp31+grp32+grp33+grp34+grp35+grp36+grp37)
 return net
```

I am getting error below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\parsefunc.py", line 10, in <module>
    tree = ET.parse('pain1.xml')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1182, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 656, in parse
    parser.feed(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1642, in feed
    self._raiseerror(v)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1506, in _raiseerror
    raise err
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: junk after document element: line 2, column 0
```

The output which I need is after parsing is shown below

```
ABC/120928/CCT001,2012-09-28T14:07:00,ABC Corporation,2012-09-28T14:07:00,100000,11500000,Times Square,7,NY 10036,New York,US,CARCORP/086,TRF,false,2012-09-29,CARCORP INC,Times Square,7,NY 10036,New York,US,00125574999,BBBBUS33,ABC/120928/CCT001/01,ABC/4562/1,100,100,SHAR,AAAAGB2L,DEF Electronics,Corn Exchange 5th Floor,Mark Lane 55,EC3R7NE London,GB,CINV,4562,2012-09-08
ABC/120928/CCT001,2012-09-28T14:07:00,ABC Corporation,2012-09-28T14:07:00,100000,11500000,Times Square,7,NY 10036,New York,US,CARCORP/086,TRF,false,2012-09-29,CARCORP INC,Times Square,7,NY 10036,New York,US,00125574999,BBBBUS33,ABC/120928/CCT001/01,ABC/4562/1,100,100,SHAR,AAAAGB2L,DEF Electronics,Corn Exchange 5th Floor,Mark Lane 55,EC3R7NE London,GB,CINV,4562,2012-09-08
```

Is there a better approach than List Comprehension with element tree or how can I parse and get the output in the above manner to parse the other xml in the same file

**Update**

I was able to parse and produce in a single line with a new approach suggested by Parfait,but still am getting the **same error** when I tried to implement the solution below for more than one xml

import sys
import lxml.etree as ET

```
net = []

tree = ET.parse('pain001.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

line= tree.xpath('//text()')

line = map(lambda line: line.strip(), line)
net = filter(bool, line)
#str_list = filter(None, str_list)
#net = root.xpath('//*') 
net = ",".join(net)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ET.parse('pain001.xml')` fails because the file isn't really an xml file. But it does have an xml document per line, which is good because that means you don't have to load the entire document into memory to process it.

You could just continue what you are doing, but put it in a `for xmltext in open('somefile'):` loop but you can also reduce the total amount of work while you are at it. I'm kinda dope slapping myself because I wrote this in `lxml` while you use ElementTree but you could either switch over or modify the script. The idea is to write out XPath selectors for each field in a list and then use that list to pull data for each line. Sure beats typing each one out.

```
import lxml.etree
import csv

# compile xpath selectors for element text
selectors = ('GrpHdr/MsgId', 'GrpHdr/CreDtTm') # etc...
xpath = [lxml.etree.XPath('{}/text()'.format(s)) for s in selectors]

# open result csv file
with open('pain.csv', 'w') as paincsv:
    writer = csv.writer(paincsv)
    # read file with 1 'CstmrCdtTrfInitn' record per line
    with open('pain.xml') as painxml:
        # process each record
        for index, line in enumerate(painxml):
            if not line.strip(): # allow empty lines
                continue
            try:
                # each line is an xml doc
                pain001 = lxml.etree.fromstring(line)
                # move to the customer elem
                elem = pain001.find('CstmrCdtTrfInitn')
                # select each value and write to csv
                writer.writerow([xp(elem)[0].strip() for xp in xpath])
            except Exception, e:
                # give a hint where things go bad
                sys.stderr.write("Error line {}, {}".format(index, str(e)))
                raise
```

Comment: Thats PERFECT , thanks a lot Tdelaney,pulling each node string works out well for the two fields. Will try out the others as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good approach. If your file is too big you will blow up your process memory. 
If your file has always the same structure, you can directly treat line by line and make the output. 
You can also directly construct your output for a line instead of making a list.

Comment: is there a way to do it line by line with or without element tree.

Answer (score 0):

Consider XPath expression of all children in document which returns a list of element tags and text:

```
net = tree.xpath('//*')
```

However, to iterate through each repeating subroot `<pain001>` and migrate to a csv format of rows and columns, consider iteration of each node occurrence of subroot and extract corresponding tags and text.

```
import os, sys
import csv
import lxml.etree as ET

# SET CURRENT DIRECTORY
cd = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# ITERATE THROUGH ALL XML FILES
for item in os.listdir(cd):
    if item.endswith(".xml"):
        tree = ET.parse(os.path.join(cd,item))

        subroot = tree.xpath("//CstmrCdtTrfInitn")

        with open(os.path.join(cd,'MultipleXPaths.csv'), 'ab') as m:
            writer = csv.writer(m)    

            for i in range(1,len(subroot)+1):        
                nodes = tree.xpath('//CstmrCdtTrfInitn[{0}]//*'.format(i))

                cols = []
                rows = []
                for elem in nodes:
                    cols.append(elem.tag)
                    rows.append(elem.text.replace('\n','').strip())

                if i == 1:
                    print ', '.join(cols)+"\n"
                    writer.writerow(cols)    

                print ', '.join(rows)+"\n"
                writer.writerow(rows)
```

**CONSOLE PRINT OUTPUT** *(but cols and rows in csv file)*

```
GrpHdr, MsgId, CreDtTm, NbOfTxs, CtrlSum, InitgPty, Nm, PstlAdr, StrtNm, 
BldgNb, PstCd, TwnNm, Ctry, PmtInf, PmtInfId, PmtMtd, BtchBookg, 
ReqdExctnDt, Dbtr, Nm, PstlAdr, StrtNm, BldgNb, PstCd, TwnNm, Ctry, 
DbtrAcct, Id, Othr, Id, DbtrAgt, FinInstnId, BICFI, CdtTrfTxInf, PmtId, 
InstrId, EndToEndId, Amt, InstdAmt, ChrgBr, CdtrAgt, FinInstnId, BICFI, 
Cdtr, Nm, PstlAdr, AdrLine, AdrLine, AdrLine, AdrLine, CdtrAcct, Id, 
Othr, Id, Purp, Cd, RmtInf, Strd, RfrdDocInf, Tp, CdOrPrtry, Cd, Nb, RltdDt

, ABC/120928/CCT001, 2012-09-28T14:07:00, 100000, 11500000, , ABC 
Corporation, , Times Square, 7, NY 10036, New York, US, , CARCORP/086, 
TRF, false, 2012-09-29, , CARCORP INC, , Times Square, 7, NY 10036, New 
York, US, , , , 00125574999, , , BBBBUS33, , , ABC/120928/CCT001/01, 
ABC/4562/4, , 100, SHAR, , , AAAAGB2L, , DEF Electronics, , Corn 
Exchange 5th Floor, Mark Lane 55, EC3R7NE London, GB, , , , 
23683707994125, , GDDS, , , , , , CINV, 4562, 2012-09-08

, ABC/120928/CCT001, 2012-09-28T14:07:00, 100000, 11500000, , ABC 
Corporation, , Times Square, 7, NY 10036, New York, US, , CARCORP/086, 
TRF, false, 2012-09-29, , CARCORP INC, , Times Square, 7, NY 10036, New 
York, US, , , , 00125574999, , , BBBBUS33, , , ABC/120928/CCT001/01, 
ABC/4562/4, , 100, SHAR, , , AAAAGB2L, , DEF Electronics, , Corn 
Exchange 5th Floor, Mark Lane 55, EC3R7NE London, GB, , , ,    
23683707994125, , GDDS, , , , , , CINV, 4562, 2012-09-08
```

Comment: i had updated my code according to your idea for a single file,however I am still getting the same error as

Comment: \lxml.etree.c:111124)
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Extra content at the end of the document, line 2, col
umn 1

Comment: I tried with your above code tried to print till subroot ,it was throwing the error

Comment: Your xml file is not well-formed. Can you post beginning and end of your file? There should always be a root node (something above the subroot, `<pain001>`.

Comment: I corrected that part, tks for that . I am trying to make corrections to code  and make the code compatible with Python 2.7.Could you also repost the code with 2.7 compatible, so that I recheck with your idea

Comment: Only compatibility issue I can see is the print lines. I adjusted it. Let me know if your run into other issues.

Comment: I just found out these input files are  a bunch of unique files going upto 100k records sitting seperately in a database with starting tag as <pain001> and ending with <pain001> with unique values.The root tag is <pain001>. What it means is we are pulling out the 100k records from the database  and doing the parsing and these needs to parsed as such and given the o/p as I have shown it above.Is it possible to do it

Comment: Is it a possible to take all the xml files in a list or map , define a function that parses the xml and returns the value to csv writer or is there a better approach u have in mind

Comment: Use the next node as the subroot `<CstmrCdtTrfInitn>` and iterate through all same structured xml files in a directory. And change the csv writer from `'w'` to `'a'` to append instead of write over. See edit.

Comment: yeah, got that , instead of newline ' ' and text replace , do we have anything compatible with 2.7

Comment: I got these two errors , AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: Remove `newline` and add the binary format to append for `'ab'`. Also, replace() is a 2.7 string operator. However, the items in `nodes` is empty (i.e., None). Is there a `<CstmrCdtTrfInitn>` in document? And if so how many per xml?

Comment: Yes, there is a starting and ending tag  of  <CstmrCdtTrfInitn> in a single xml. so two tags per xml file and totally if its added up it comes around 200k(100k X2) in the whole file

Comment: is this stmt  correct , My file path is for the pain1.xml is 'C:/python27/pain1.xml'                                                                                     cd = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(pain1.xml))